# Scrapy crawler, removing comma from the string

Tags: python, scrapy

```
def parse_item(self, response):
   for jobs in response.xpath('//div[@itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting"]'):
    item = IndeedCoUkItem()
    item["jobtitle"] = jobs.xpath('*[@class="jobtitle"]/a//text()').extract()
    yield item
```

item saved to a CSV file as,

jobtitle

"Senior ,Embedded, ,Software, Engineer"

Hi,

The above is a snippet from my scrapy crawler code. I would like to have the output be comma and white space free. That is from "Senior ,Embedded, ,Software, Engineer" to this "Senior Embedded Software Engineer". I tried to use replace() like ..extract()[0].replace(",",""), but it didn't work. Any help/ suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to print / log the list which gets into the `item['jobtitle]` field? If it is a list (well, it is a list) then the export to a CSV file converts this list to a comma separated entry.

Try to look at the result and join the list to one:

```
item["jobtitle"] = ' '.join(jobs.xpath('*[@class="jobtitle"]/a//text()').extract())
```

If the items contain extra white-spaces but not all of them, you can use `map` and `strip` on the elements:

```
item["jobtitle"] = ' '.join(map(unicode.strip,jobs.xpath('*[@class="jobtitle"]/a//text()').extract()))
```

This walks throug all the elements and `strip`s off the whitespaces at the beginning and at the end.

Alternatively you could use `normalize-space` of XPath:

```
item["jobtitle"] = ' '.join(jobs.xpath('normalize-space(*[@class="jobtitle"]/a//text())').extract())
```

Comment: GHajba, your solutions seems to work (no more comma) but I got whitespace remained there. Here is the actual output,                    [u'Senior ', u'Embedded', u' ', u'Software', u' Engineer']
[u'Embedded', u' C']
[u'Software', u' Engineer, Compiler']

Comment: In this case you can use `strip` or `normalize-space` on the elements. Both examples included in the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GHajba, map and strip method worked :) but not the normalize-space, it striped the whole string after the first word.

Comment: I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score -1):

```
item["jobtitle"] = (jobs.xpath('*[@class="jobtitle"]/a//text()').extract()).replace(',', '')
```

Comment: There is no explanation of what this code does, or why.  Please add clarification to add to the value that this answer brings.